# How is it possible to use the Thor Browser to open a website and net the Programm paste in text and klick Buttons on the website by XPath

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, tor

I tried working with selenium but it seems that I need Firefox for any reason and I´m not sure if this would be save enough.
I also tried Torpy but I couldn't find how I could use it to Paste text in Boxen or Click Buttons that are lochtet by x path.
(Hope my discription is mostyl correct, kinda new to all this Programming stuff)

```
**With Selenium**

TOR_PATH = '/Applications/Tor Browser.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox'

# Start the Tor browser
binary = TOR_PATH
if os.path.exists(binary) is False:
    raise ValueError("Binary path to Tor firefox is invalid.")
firefox_binary = FirefoxBinary(binary)
browser = None
def get_browser(binary=None):
    global browser
    # just one instance of a browser opens, remove global for multiple instances
    if not browser:
        browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_binary=binary)
    return browser
if __name__ == "__main__":
    browser = get_browser(binary=firefox_binary)

# Open the Google sign-up page with the Tor browser
browser.get('example')

# Enter first and last name
fristname_input = browser.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body')
firstname_input.send_keys(first_name)
time.sleep(random.randint(2, 20))
```

```
**With TorPy**

with TorClient() as tor:
    with tor.create_circuit(3) as circ:
        # Webseite öffnen
        with circ.create_stream(('example', 443)) as stream:
            stream.send('GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: www.example.com\r\n\r\n'.encode())
            response = stream.recv(1024)

        # Vorname und Nachname eingeben
        with circ.create_stream(('https://example.com', 443)) as stream:
            stream.send(f'POST /register HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: example.com\r\nContent-Length: 43\r\n\r\nfirst_name={first_name}&last_name={last_name}'.encode())
            response = stream.recv(1024)
```